# Issue with training a Graph Convolutional Network

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, graph-neural-network

I am trying to use Pytorch to come up with a Graph Neural Network model that allows me to predict links in a network of alliances between organizations. When I try to train my model, I get an "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'". What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch_geometric.data import Data
from torch_geometric.transforms import RandomLinkSplit
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

# Load the edgelist from a CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('Alliances_torch.csv')

# Extract the source and target nodes from the edgelist
src = df['Source'].values
tgt = df['Target'].values

# Compute the total number of nodes
num_nodes = max(max(src), max(tgt)) + 1

# Convert the edgelist into a PyTorch Geometric graph dataset
data = Data(edge_index=torch.tensor([src, tgt]), num_nodes=num_nodes)

# Split the dataset into training and test sets
transform = RandomLinkSplit(num_val=0.1, num_test=0.1)
data = transform(data)

# Define the graph convolutional network model
class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_features, hidden_size)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_size, num_classes)
    
    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return x

# Initialize the model
model = GCN(num_features=1, hidden_size=16, num_classes=1)

# Define the optimizer and loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

The actual error is raised when I am trying to train the model.  Here is the code for that:

```
# Train the model
def train():
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data.x, data.train_pos_edge_index)
    loss = criterion(out.flatten(), data.train_pos_edge_label.float())
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

# Evaluate the model
def test():
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        out = model(data.x, data.test_pos_edge_index)
        pred = (out > 0).flatten()
        correct = pred.eq(data.test_pos_edge_label).sum().item()
        acc = correct / data.test_pos_edge_label.size(0)
    return acc

# Train the model for 50 epochs
for epoch in range(1, 51):
    train()
    test_acc = test()
    print('Epoch {:03d}, Test Acc: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, test_acc))
```

The whole error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23476\3486806602.py in <module>
     20 # Train the model for 50 epochs
     21 for epoch in range(1, 51):
---> 22     train()
     23     test_acc = test()
     24     print('Epoch {:03d}, Test Acc: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, test_acc))

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23476\3486806602.py in train()
      3     model.train()
      4     optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 5     out = model(data.x, data.train_pos_edge_index)
      6     loss = criterion(out.flatten(), data.train_pos_edge_label.float())
      7     loss.backward()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: I'd recommend providing the full error message with trace. Also once you know where the error is being thrown you can print some of the variables, which makes it easier to see what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

`data = transform(data)` returns `train_data, val_data, test_data`. You can see the code here: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/transforms/random_link_split.html#RandomLinkSplit

Since `data` is a tuple of `(train_data, val_data, test_data)`, you'll at least need `data[0]` to get to the training data, and also you should use distinct data (e.g. `data[2]`) for your test loop. I don't know if the actual data has an `x` attribute but that's why you get the particular error message.